# Как записать на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    if($('.wpcf7-list-item input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
      $('.wpcf7-form-control p input:submit').css('color', '#000000');
    } else {
      $('.wpcf7-form-control p input:submit').css('color', '#707981');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let submitInput = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form-control p input[type="submit"]');
let checkbox = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-list-item input[type="submit"]');

if ( checkbox.checked ) {
    submitInput.style.color = '#000000';
} else {
    submitInput.style.color = '#707981';
}
```

Comment: (index):1448 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.wpcf7-form-control p input:submit' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Поправил ответ.